# How do I see that there is a conflict in the LR(0) items automata?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, automata, lr-grammar

There is something I don't fully get about the `LR(0)`. I'm trying to figure out when grammar is not `LR(0)`. As I understand I build the `LR(0)` items automata. Then I need to look for conflict. But I don't think that I fully understand when there is a conflict between two items in the `LR(0)` items automata.
Is it possible to clear things up about this part? When do I know is there a conflict in the `LR(0)` items automata? Would be helpful to see an example or two (not for the grammar itself, rather for two items that have a conflict off some kind).

For example for:

```
S ::= T C
T ::= char
T ::= int
C ::= [ num ] C
C ::= ''
```

I get:

[image]

Why is there a conflict between 4 and 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a "conflict between 4 and 8". (That wouldn't make sense, since the parsing machine is always in exactly one state.) Each of the two states (independently) has a conflict.

LR(0) parsers cannot use lookahead to predict the action, so every state must either have:

1. A shift transition for every input, or
2. The same reduction action for every input

That means that if there is a single item in the state's itemset with the • at the end (i.e. a reducible item), then it must be the only item in the itemset. Any other item would either be a shift or a different reduction. And that's not the case for states 4 and 8 in your machine; both of them have the item `C ::= •`, along with other items not ending with `•`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228976/discussion-between-rici-and-vesii).