# Why this grammar has Reduce/Reduce conflict in LR(0)?

Tags: parsing, compilation, grammar, lr-grammar

I have the following grammar:

```
S -> a b D E
S -> A B E F
D -> M x
E -> N y
F -> z
M -> epsilon
N -> epsilon
```

My textbook says there is a Reduce/Reduce conflict in LR(0). I built a diagram and found out that there is a state:

```
S -> a b . D E
S -> A B . E F
D -> . M x
E -> . N y
M -> .
N -> .
```

The textbook says that it's a Reduce/Reduce conflict. I'm trying to figure out why. If I build the SLR table I get the following row (3 is the state above):

[image]

That's because:

- Follow(M)={x} so we can do reduce to rule 6 from state 3.
- Follow(N)={y} so we can do reduce to rule 7 from state 3.

I was taught that there is a conflict S/R if there is a cell with S/R and conflict R/R if there is a cell with R/R. But I don't see two Rs in the same cell in the table. So why is it a reduce/reduce conflict?

Answer (score 1):

You show an SLR(1) parsing table, in which the columns correspond to a lookahead of length 1. It's correct, and there is no conflict.

But here we're talking about an LR(0) machine, in which there is no lookahead. (That's the 0 in LR(0).) The only decision the machine can make is to shift or reduce, and since it cannot use lookahead, it can only use the state itself. A given state must be either a shift state or a reduce state (and, if a reduce state, which production is being reduced).

(In case it's confusing, and it often is, the concept of lookahead does not refer to the use of the shifted symbol to decide which state to transition to. The transition is taken based on the shifted symbol, which is at that point no longer part of the lookahead.)

So in that state, there is no possible shift action; in all items in the itemset, either the dot is at the end or the next symbol is a non-terminal (implying a GOTO action after returning from a reduce).

But the state does not have a unique reduction. Depending on the lookahead, the parsers needs to choose to reduce M or to reduce N. And since there is no lookahead, the decision cannot be made and hence it's a conflict.

Comment: I see. So why when we want to prove that grammar is LR(0) we build the automaton of items **and** the table I tried to build? Why building the automaton is not enough?

Comment: @vesii: Didn't we go through this at depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268824/how-do-i-see-that-there-is-a-conflict-in-the-lr0-items-automata ? Anyway, who says that you have to build an SLR(1) table in order to demonstrate that a grammar is LR(0)?

Comment: It's a bit different from the question there. My question is what's the difference between LR(0) table and SLR(1) table? In SLR(1) we do reduce by checking the Follow set. What should we check if LR(0)?

Comment: Is it just the whole line? I mean, should the whole line be reduce in LR(0), in case we have dot at the end of one of the elements?

Comment: @vesii: yes, it's the whole line, which is to say the state itself. There's no other information available because lookahead is not allowed.

Comment: And that's precisely what I said in my answer to the other question: "every state must either have: (1) A shift transition for every input, or (2) The same reduction action for every input."

Comment: For clarity: building the state machine requires following shift actions. But that's independent of the parsing table, which need not be constructed because, as mentioned, the parse action does not depend in any way on the input (although the state transition does). The difference between a shift (which absorbs the next symbol) and lookahead (which looks at the next *k* symbols without consuming any of them) is more marked when *k* ≠ 1. But it's worth keeping straight even if *k* = 1.